# I want to bind dynamic count value in ng-repeat loop?

Tags: html, angularjs

This is HTML code for reference and I looping layers but there columns values change on every loop. I have concatenated index value to table column but not working?

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample"><br>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Inside Layers</th>
                            <th scope="col">Outside Layers</th>
                            <th scope="col">Text</th>
                            <th scope="col">Color</th>
                            <th scope="col">Font</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="Layer in Layers" class="rem1" ng-init="index = $index + 1">
                            <td class="invert">{{Layer.InSideLayer + '' + index}}</td>
                            <td class="invert">{{Layer.OutSideLayer + '' + index}}</td>
                            <td class="invert">{{Layer.TextOnLayer + '' + index}}</td>
                            <td class="invert">{{Layer.TextColorLayer + '' + index}}</td>
                            <td class="invert">{{Layer.TextFontLayer + '' + index}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain more about your issue

Comment: here is Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kz54t9vL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
{{Layer["InSideLayer" + index]}}
```

your code `{{Layer.InSideLayer + '' + index}}` won't work as you are actually concatenating it on runtime so it will return it as undefined.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b13syfjL/)